# Add accessibility to Python program, particularly screen reader functionality

Tags: python, accessibility, screen-readers, wcag, nvda

I have created a simple Python program that will gather hardware specs and request input from the user.  It is using PySimpleGui and the text for the user input questions is not getting picked up by my screen reader (I'm using NVDA).

P.S. It only needs to work on Windows.

Comment: have you already tried with the native Win Screen Narrator? I have no best option than NVDA, if you're willing to stay on a free-of-charge tool.

Answer (score 0):

PySimpleGUI, according to its [documentation](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/), is a wrapper around four frameworks: Tkinter, PyQT, wxPython and Remi (something webby, again from the docs).

So, in order to make your software accessible, you need to know what is your underlying framework. Tkinter (which, I presume, is the default) cannot produce accessible environments at all as of October 2021. PyQT requires some work to be able to do it, but I don't know whether PySimpleGUI provides those tools. The same is for Remi: webby environments can be accessible, but I have no idea about what PySimpleGUI provides accessibility-wise.

wxPython is the best choice here, it is known to power lots of accessible apps (including NVDA itself, ironically!). So I would go for wxPython as the underlying framework.